# How is the routing of Skype?

Tags: ip, skype

While packet sniffing with tcpdump, is it usual to have different IP's connected while normal chatting in Skype? While using Videochat a direct IP?

I have doubts about the logins.
E.g. if someone could steal my creds and login from somewhere else at the same time.

Comment: Hi GiaRui - this is not a security question as per our scope. It may be on topic on SuperUser, but not in its current form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I changed a bit the question, I'm sorry for any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

Skype started off as a P2P based software until Microsoft bought it. This also means they want a peek through all the traffic that there is.

If you resolve the IP addresses to the zones or hostname, I am pretty sure it will map to the Microsoft AS (Autonomous System)

Answer (score 0):

This is dependant on the version of skype. But yes, skype makes several connections to outside sources. As I understand it, Skype used to be primarily P2P (meaning that your client directly connects to the person you're talking to and vice versa). Nowadays the traffic is proxied so that you cannot get the other persons IP address. So yes, you are likely to have a number of TCP/UDP connections while using skype.

Comment: During a chat I noted some misfunctions, perhaps just a quality problem. However it's a while ago. Thanks